# TFS 2010 Build ClickOnce deployment files

Tags: tfs, clickonce

My application consists of a Server and Client. Each of our customers has a PC that will host the server and a clickonce deployment of the client that they can then install on whatever PCs they want to have it. I am currently trying to find out the best way to handle this since the support for publishing clickonce installers from TFS Build seems to be nonexistent.

The publish URL for each customer will be different so I would like to have a separate build for each customer that just reuses the binaries built for the server and client.

My ideal solution would be having a team project for the code (Server and Client) and then a separate team project with folders for each customer. The Customers Team Project would also house the binaries from the builds of the Server and Client. Then I would create a build for each customer that would change the publish url of the client clickonce .application file and re-sign it.

The biggest place I am stuck right now is how to get the clickonce publish files from Team Build, but I am also curious if there is just a totally better way to do this that I have missed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See ["Building ClickOnce Applications from the Command Line [MSDN]"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx)

I think you could set up a [MSBuild workflow activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.msbuild.aspx) in Team Foundation Build to publish each of your customer's projects, if you're using the default Workflow template.

Comment: I have followed the instructions [here](http://thebasilet.blogspot.com/2010/10/tfs-2010-team-build-clickonce.html), which basically boils down to running msbuild with the target:Publish switch and it seems to work, but it doesn't create the same directory structure that Visual Studio does when it does a publish (Application Files/App_Version/*.deploy files), instead it is just a flat structure.

Comment: Also, the output is missing resource files (Icons, etc...) that are normally copied by Visual Studio.